# Autowiring in spring only in config

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

We can autowire by field, setter, constructor. But we can also define beans only in configuration class and not use autowire at all. What are advanatages of doing so? example config :

```
@Configuration
class DrawingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    DrawingFacade drawingFacade(DrawingRepository repository) {
        DrawingFactory factory = new DrawingFactory();
        return new DrawingFacade(repository, factory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define a bean in a configuration file you still need to autowire it, but you don't need to annotate it with `@Component/@Service/@Repository` annotation. It is just way to say that this bean is a `@Component`.